# SQL query generating 88PB of data and consuming all server resources

Tags: sql, database, oracle, debugging

I´m debugging a SQL query that is creating some data looping, generating 88PB of data, when should be just a relatory. This uses 95% of 48 cores server and turns all the system slow, consequently.

This is medical center data.

I think there's a loop inside loop problem, but would like to listen some optimization opinions.

There's some clear bug, or it's just a matter of optimization?

```
A.DT_ATENDIMENTO AS DT_ATENDIMENTO,
    A.CD_ATENDIMENTO AS ATENDIMENTO   ,
    P.NM_PRESTADOR   AS PRESTADOR     ,
    CASE
            WHEN P.CD_TIP_PRESTA IN (4,55,14,66,65,60)
            THEN 'ENFERMAGEM'
            WHEN P.CD_TIP_PRESTA IN (8,68,10,5,62,9,70,69,56,64)
            THEN 'MEDICA'
            WHEN P.CD_TIP_PRESTA IN (9,57,63,69)
            THEN 'NUTRICIONISTA'
            WHEN P.CD_TIP_PRESTA IN (10,58,64,70)
            THEN 'PSICOLOGO'
            WHEN P.CD_TIP_PRESTA IN (5)
            THEN 'FISIOTERAPEUTA'
    END                 AS TP_PRESTADOR  ,
    TP.NM_TIP_PRESTA    AS TIPO_PRESTADOR,
    ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA AS CD_UNIDADE    ,
    ME.DS_MULTI_EMPRESA AS UNIDADE       ,
    CASE
            WHEN P.TP_SITUACAO = 'A'
            THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
    END AS QTD_ATIVO,
    CASE
            WHEN P.TP_SITUACAO = 'I'
            THEN '1'
            ELSE '0'
    END AS QTD_INATIVO
FROM    PW_DOCUMENTO_CLINICO PDC,
    PAGU_OBJETO PO          ,
    ATENDIME A              ,
    PRESTADOR P             ,
    MULTI_EMPRESAS ME       ,
    TIP_PRESTA TP
    WHERE   PDC.CD_OBJETO           = PO.CD_OBJETO
    AND PDC.CD_ATENDIMENTO IS NOT NULL
    AND PO.SN_ASSINATURA    ='S'
    AND PDC.TP_STATUS       = 'FECHADO'
    AND A.CD_ATENDIMENTO    = PDC.CD_ATENDIMENTO
    AND PDC.CD_PRESTADOR    = P.CD_PRESTADOR
    AND TRUNC(PDC.DH_CRIACAO,'DD') BETWEEN To_Date('01/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy') AND To_Date('26/11/2021','dd/mm/yyyy')
    AND A.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA   = ME.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA
    AND A.CD_MULTI_EMPRESA  IN ('6')
    AND P.CD_TIP_PRESTA      = TP.CD_TIP_PRESTA
    AND P.CD_PRESTADOR NOT  IN('5','103','141','56','103','104','142','178','3')
    AND P.CD_TIP_PRESTA NOT IN (20)
    AND PDC.CD_PACIENTE NOT IN ('2135','6316','6359','6872','6728','6530','6387','6560','6652','6770','6324','6752','6863','6366','6543','6472','6298', '6497','6379','6749','6496','6528','6777','6518','6374','6556','6501','6449','6535','8005','8253','22254','41014','56617','79769','90475','103234','118950','122774', '127497','35187');
```

[image]

Comment: I read the title of the question, and thought "I bet it uses pre-ANSI92 join syntax". The 92 is a year, by the way, indicating just how long it's been possible to use a syntax that helps avoid writing some accidental cartesian mega-explosion

Comment: So.. help us out with some numbers.. For each of the where clauses mentioned, how many records does it apply to? Some of your tables here have a large number of rows, possibly joined with another table that also has a large number of matching rows. If you have a thousand rows with ID 1 on the left and a thousand with ID 1 on the right, you create a million rows... You only need to do that a few times to get to petabytes of data. If you're struggling to debug, make it `SELECT *` and comment out all but one tables, then join in one by one til the resultset goes huge, then find out why

Comment: The output accuses  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN as the culprit, with two 38Pb 

The problem is the pre-selection in the start of the code, the first CASE

How can I rewrite that without the merge join cartesian processing?

Comment: What does *pre-selection in the start of the code* mean? Post the full execution plan

Comment: I was talking about the first CASE, where the problem occurs.

Comment: Not quite sure how a CASE WHEN like that causes a cartesian explosion.. Post the full execution plan

Comment: The output:

https://postimg.cc/tnFfnQ62

Comment: @Philos Can you add the beginning of the query? The plan is so ridiculously horrible for this query, I wonder if something is forcing the optimizer to choose a bad plan. Are there hints, like `select /*+ FULL(PDC) ORDERED ...)`? Also, can you please add the explain plan output as text to the question? (It helps if you can keep editing the question instead of posting in comments.) And be sure to include the entire explain plan, especially the "Note" section if there is one. Performance questions on Stack Overflow are difficult, but if you keep editing someone can probably help.

Comment: According to the fact that each plan step increases the number of rows exponentially, looks like `where` predicates are irrelevant to the tables used. There's no any filter on `atendime`, for example. Please, show full execution plan: `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'ALL'))`